# Mailchimp merge-tag to check if the string is equal to two quotes ""

Tags: escaping, mailchimp, mandrill

I currently need to check, if the merge-tag is exactly equal "empty-string" quotes `sampleTag=""`, meaning it is `"\"\""`.

It works for common strings like:
`sampleTag=a`
But it always converts quotes to `&quot;&quot;`

Also i've tried:
`=""`,
`=\"\"`.
Neither worked